# How to change field data in crystal report on VB6

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I want to change the field data on my crystal report specifically. I want to add date range generating from my `DateTimePicker`. It shows no data when i generate.

```
With CrystalReport1
    .ReportFileName = App.Path & "/detailedvoucher2.rpt"

    .SelectionFormula = "{voucdtl.v_date} in Datetime (" & dtfrom.Value & ") to  Datetime(" & dtto.Value & ")"
    .WindowState = crptMaximized

    .Action = 1 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The text-delimiters are missing for the `Datetime`-function.

Code should look as follows:

```
.SelectionFormula = "{voucdtl.v_date} in Datetime ('" & dtfrom.Value & "') to  Datetime('" & dtto.Value & "')"
```

I'm not sure how the `Value` of `DateTimePicker` will be formatted in VB6 by default.

You also need to ensure the format is valid for the `Datetime`-function.